# WebLogic unable to resolve jndi datasource

Tags: java, weblogic, datasource, jndi

I have application which gets datasource from WebLogic through jndi name.

```
JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiFactory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
jndiFactory.setJndiName(currentDSSettings.getJndi());
jndiFactory.setResourceRef(true);
jndiFactory.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
jndiFactory.setLookupOnStartup(false);
jndiFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
datasource = (DataSource) jndiFactory.getObject();
```

I configured jndi datasource names in `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  profiles.active: development

---
spring:
  profiles: production
datasources:
   -  dbName : myDataSource
      driverClass:
      url:
      jndi: RCDB-SMS-JNDI
      db:
      server:
      user:
      password:
```

I configured it at WebLogic server, specified particular target. I tested this datasource, and WebLogic says that test was successful. But when i try to deploy application, i get following error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve 'RCDB-SMS-JNDI'. Resolved ''; remaining name 'RCDB-SMS-JNDI'
```

I need to determine is problem in datasource configuration at WebLogic or is problem in getting datasource in my java code. Am i able to test getting datasource without deploying application?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you should prefix your JndiName with a path. Try to replace your code with the following one according to your path definitions :

```
JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiFactory = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
jndiFactory.setJndiName("java:comp/env/" + env.getProperty("sta.datasource.name", "jdbc/mySpace"));
jndiFactory.setResourceRef(true);
jndiFactory.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
jndiFactory.setLookupOnStartup(false);
try {
    jndiFactory.afterPropertiesSet();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException | NamingException e) {
    throw new SQLException("Datasource not found", e);
}
datasource = (DataSource) jndiFactory.getObject();
```

*or* `application.yml` may be configured

```
server:
  contextPath: jdbc/mySpace
```